# list index out of range json dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, iot

im trying to get a varible from ubidots on omega2, this variable is a json dict and the values are 1 or 0 (its a switch). When a start the code remind me list index out of range error. (sorry for my english :( )
Error:
File "main.py", line 23 in **main**
if tapparellasu[0]['value']:
IndexError: list index out of range

The output of: print (tapparellasu) is []
and the output of print TapparellaSu is the name of the Ubidots variable (and so the program can get the ubidots variable but i can read the value from the dict.)

```
import os
import json
import onionGpio
import time
import ubidots
from ubidots import ApiClient
api = ApiClient(token='wefwfwfwefwefwefwefrwgewrgerfgwef')
gpio6 = onionGpio.OnionGpio(6)
gpio7 = onionGpio.OnionGpio(7)
tapparellasu = 0
status = gpio6.setOutputDirection(0)
status = gpio7.setOutputDirection(0)


def __main__():
    TapparellaSu = api.get_variable('uywqegfuywefkwaeuiyfyuwefjukghwef')
    tapparellasu = TapparellaSu.get_values(1)
    if tapparellasu[0]['value']:
        status = gpio6.setValue(1)
    else:
        status = gpio6.setValue(0)
    print tapparellasu[0]['value']
    time.sleep(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

Comment: Please paste the complete exception you get, so that one actually knows where the issue might be. Also the code you pasted has broken indentation, so it won't work as is.

Comment: Thanks, @Bit have fixed my indentation and i've write the compleate exception. U can also find on GitHub the code for ubidots that i've used..

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the Output of `print(tapparellasu)` before `if tapparellasu[0]['value']`.

Comment: Done ;) ty for your help!